# How many activities created in android application

Tags: android

I have two Activity with button, that switch between it

```
Intent intent1=new Intent(Act1.this,Act2.class);
startActivity(intent1);
```

and

```
Intent intent1=new Intent(Act2.this,Act1.class);
startActivity(intent1);
```

If I switch ten times by button, how much Activites will I have?
If I push back on device button, I can see ten different state Act1 or Act2.

Comment: Do some maths! Not hard!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the launch mode of your activities. Look at [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html#TaskLaunchModes).

But by default you will have the initial activity and 10 new instances -> 11 activities.